# Syntax error in PHP with an array

Tags: php

I have this type of array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Success] => The file was uploaded.
    )[1] => Array(
        [Error] => The file doesn 't exist.
    )[2] => Array(
        [Success] => The file is supported.
    )
)
```

In my code I use to make this to display a table with `Error` and `Success` messages.

```
foreach($results as $innerArr) {
    if(array_keys($innerArr)[0]=='Error') { $css = 'style="background:red"'; }
    if(array_keys($innerArr)[0]=='Success') { $css = 'style="background:green"'; }

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td '.$css.'></td>';
    echo '<td>'.array_values($innerArr)[0].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

My problem is:
I get all the time this type of error:

```
[Tue Mar 31 09:44:48 2015] [error] [client 172.***.140.***] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in upload.php on line 229, referer: http://****.com/verification/index.html
```

As I have PHP 5.2, how can I solve my problem please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is on line 229?

Comment: Ligne 229 is `array_keys($innerArr)[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to PHP 5.4

Alternatively, you'll have to screw around with temporary variables. Function return value dereferencing was only added in 5.4

Answer (score 2):

That here is not working. When you use the `array_values` function you have to save them in a new variable if you use PHP 5.2.

```
$values = array_values($innerArr);
echo '<td>'.$values[0].'</td>';
```

What you can do is to update your PHP version to PHP 5.4+ or higher.

Comment: Ok, but the line looks this one : `array_keys($innerArr)[0]`.